# How can i find specific charater in strings between two word?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having trouble coming up with the regex I need to do this find/replace in Notepad++. I would like to find/replace specific character in strings between two words

for example

```
msgid "flower"
"test hold"
msgstr
```

I would like to find multiple `o` character between `msgid "` and `msgstr` and replace with `a` character. The result is

```
msgid "flawer"
"test hald"
msgstr
```

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?

Comment: im noobie, sorry, I dont know what you mean.

Comment: @Tim I think Notepad++ regular expressions use the Boost regular expression library v1.80 (as of NPP v8.4.7), which is based on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very convoluted but should work for all cases:

```
((?:^.*?msgid "|\G)(?:(?!msgstr)[\s\S])*?)o(?=(?:(?!msgid ")[\s\S])*?msgstr)
```

Replace with

```
$1a
```

See test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/CUOA7K/1)

Basically what it does is to match `o`s after seeing `msgid "`, after that get the end of previous match using `\G` and continue matching the rest of `o`s before encountering `msgstr`.

Comment: Awsome!!, I have test this regular expression and it works in all case, Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here I have written regex to perform the action above you have described.
If you replace the `o` with whatever you're searching for, you will be able to search and capture it.

This is written assuming the PCRE Regex Engine. (What I could find is the one run in Notepad++)

```
(?<=msgid ")(.*)(o)(.*)(?= msgstr)
```

Below is the replacement statement. The `a` can be replaced with whatever you wish to replace the captured text with. The `$1` represents everything after `msgid "` and before the search text. The `$3` represents anything after the captured statement and before the  `msgstr`. If you want to use the captured text anywhere in the replace statement, you can reference it with `$2`.

```
$1a$3
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will only work on a single `o` in between the markers.

Comment: Wow, So many thanks I will go to test, If i have any question, Please give me ask again :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, the statement given will only replace the `o`, however, if you read the description above, it states that you can replace the `o` with any other expression you're searching for. The assumption here is that the user will be searching for plain text, but it will also work for regular expressions matching whatever they would like.

Comment: @holtkampjs What if there are multiple `o`s between the markers? Do you want to replace all of them or just one of them? Since this answer only replaces the last occurance of `o`.

Comment: @holtkampjs Thank you for your answer, its work but If there are many o character, How modify the regular expression to replace a to multiple o ? Thank you very much

Comment: @AttawatViriyopase If you want to replace the `a` with multiple `o`'s (the capture group), you would just put the `$2` in the replace statement where you want it. For example, putting 3 o's in the replace statement, it would look like `$1$2$2$2$3`